# tkinter: Ensure image fills the whole of the canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I'm trying to make a very simple example work on my system (macOS Mojave with Python 3.6+).  I wonder if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Minimal reproducer:

```py
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
img = Image.open('lenna.png')
root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=img.width, height=img.height,
    background='blue')
canvas.pack()
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
imagesprite = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW, image=tkimg)
root.mainloop()
```

Image (512x512 pixels in size):

[image: lenna.png]

Here is what I see:

[image: canvas displayed]

As you can see, the image is about 3 pixels displaced to the top left (note blue bars on the right and bottom of the image).  As the canvas has the same dimensions of the input image, I'd thought this code should make the image occupy the whole of the canvas, but is not the case on the tested python versions (3.6.7, 3.6.8 and 3.7.2 on macOS Mojave, installed through conda; Python 3.7.2 installed through homebrew).

N.B.: This example works flawlessly on Linux.

Another note: Changing the `create_image` call above so that it is anchored on `(3,3)` instead of `(0,0)` solves this problem, rather magically. Not sure of the origin of these 3 pixels displacements...

Question: Without anchoring the image on (3,3) instead of (0,0) - how to ensure the image actually occupies the whole of the canvas?  Is there something wrong with my code or is this a bug (no trace anywhere - but maybe my search-fu is not so advanced)?

Affected version which I tested with:

- python 3.6.7, 3.6.8, 3.7.2 from conda (defaults channel) with TclVersion and TkVersion = 8.6 (`tkinter.TkVersion`)
- python 3.7.2 from homebrew with TclVersion and TkVersion = 8.5

Comment: When you create the `Canvas`, try also specifying `borderwidth=0` and `highlightthickness=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas has a border and a highlight ring which causes the interior of the canvas to be slightly offset. Set the `borderwidth` and `highlightthicknes` options to zero. And since you are relying on `pack` defaults which may be different on different platforms, you should explicitly set the padding to zero too.